# How to toggle a Bootstrap dropdown menu from a link?

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap dropdown menu that is working fine.  What I'd like to do is also trigger the opening of the menu by clicking on a link elsewhere on the page.  (This makes sense because of what's in the menu item, etc.)  The doc page says that having the link do something like `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()`, or maybe `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle')` should do this, but neither is working for me.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(".dropdown").addClass("open");
```

and

```
$(".dropdown").removeClass("open");
```

Comment: Thanks -- I tried it (or a `toggleClass()` version of it), but it didn't work.  I groveled around the Bootstrap code for awhile, and its toggle activities clear the menus such that they remove the `open` class right after I set it.  What I've done (but am not particularly proud of) is to give my link the same dropdown-related attributes as the dropdown menu (`class='dropdown-toggle'` and `data-toggle='dropdown'`), and give the div containing this link the dropdown class.  Then, when the page loads, the same jQuery call that sets up the dropdown menu sets up my link....

Comment: ...I need another copy of the contents of the original dropdown, and the positioning is relative to the containing div, but at least something is coming up.  Sigh...

Comment: Followup: the `.dropdown` class brings with it a `position:relative` style.  So, clear this by giving your link-containing div `position:inherit`, assigning `position:relative` to some div higher in the tree, and playing with margin settings to get what you want.  I still wish I knew of a cleaner way to do this, but at least I have something working.