# AngularJS/Bootstrap: trigger dropdown from link with a directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I am trying to trigger a Bootstrap dropdown to open with a link outside of the `.dropdown` container class.  I tried creating a directive to call something like `$('a.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle')` but that's not working for me.

This looks very similar to:
[How to toggle a Bootstrap dropdown menu from a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944526/how-to-toggle-a-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-from-a-link) but that doesn't seem to apply 100% and there's no clear answer to it.  I'd prefer not to check if the div that has the `dropdown` class also has `open` and show and hide based off of that.  Is there a correct implementation of this?

Here is my plunkr showing you what I mean.  The first "show link" link does nothing when it should be toggling the dropdown of the other "show link" link.  Twitter Bootstrap documentation does say to use the `$().dropdown('toggle')` to toggle but that doesn't seem to work.

http://plnkr.co/edit/KF60Um2KjzPX0dr6WqKC?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the dropdown.js plugin? I'm seeing an error using firebug saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dropdown'
```

Please refer to this: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns