# Trigger Bootstrap Dropdown with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to open a Bootstrap dropdown menu via JavaScript. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944526/how-to-toggle-a-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-from-a-link) suggests adding and removing the `open` class, but when I try that, nothing happens. Adding a different class works fine. Is Bootstrap preventing me from doing this?

Working sample on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8p6Wd/1).

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Add Classes" />
<div class="dropdown">
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown Trigger</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">Dropdown Content</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('input').click(function () {
    $('.dropdown').addClass('open');
    $('.dropdown').addClass('test-class');
});
```

Comment: @Popnoodles, I have added code from jsfiddle to question.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Your main problem is that you aren't stopping the click event from propagating to the `document`. Bootstrap sets an event listener on the `document` that closes dropdowns.

```
$('input').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next('.dropdown').find('[data-toggle=dropdown]').dropdown('toggle');
});
```

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/8p6Wd/2/

Comment: @Popnoodles That's true but the OP's code doesn't set any of the internal state or trigger the custom events usually associated with the Dropdown plugin.

Answer (score 2):

try this...

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <input type="button" value="Classes" data-toggle="dropdown"/>
    <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown Trigger</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">Dropdown Content</div>
</div>
```