# Toggling navbar dropdown with external button

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm using bootstrap navbar and I have a dropdown on it. Everything works fine there. What I need now is a secondary separate button on the page to toggle said dropdown aswell.

I have managed to toggle the dropdown using the external button but when I ever interact with the actual dropdown button the secondary button stops working.

```
$(document).on("click","#servicesBtn",function(){         
   $(".servicesDropdown").toggleClass("show");
   $("#navbarDropdown").attr("aria-expanded", "true");
})
```

This is the code I use to achieve the toggling of dropdown. I have noticed after interacting with the main dropdown button the secondary button doesn't add the necessary classes to the dopdown to toggle it. In chrome dev tools it shows flashing as if it's changing but no classes are added.

How do I make it so both dropdown togglers work together, without one breaking the other?

**SOLUTION:**

I have found the solution. This is how to trigger dropdown with an external button: `$('.servicesDropdown').find('[data-toggle=dropdown]').dropdown('toggle');`
Note that `.servicesDropdown` is a custom class thats in the div surrounding the dropdown.

All credit goes to  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035565/trigger-bootstrap-dropdown-with-js) thread

Comment: can you "simulate" the click in jQuery? `$(document).on("click","#servicesBtn", function() { $('#dropdownID').click();   });`

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio Seems like a logical solution but for some reason it doesn't work. The same thing is happening, dev tools show that the classes are changing(blinking) but nothing actually changes.